# Is "But if" a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

Take Tennyson's poem Flower In The Crannied Wall for an example.

> Flower in the crannied wall,
>   I pluck you out of the crannies,
>   I hold you here, root and all, in my hand,
>   Little flower—**but if** I could understand
>   What you are, root and all, and all in all,
>   I should know what God and man is.

Comment: No. _If_ is a subordinating conjunction. _But if_ is not a constituent.

Comment: I agree that "but if" is not a constituent, but conditional "if" is not a subordinator but a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ The difference lies entirely on how one prefers to label the nodes; either way, it's not an argument.